# Use SpEl to create a bean if property is specified or a default bean if it is not

Tags: spring, spring-el

I would like to inject a Bean of type `java.nio.file.Path` using a user specified application property. I would like to use SpEl to do this with the use of Spring's `@Value` annotation so that it is achieved without need to create configuration files.

Initially I have tried this:

```java
@Value("#{T(java.nio.file.Paths).get(\"${base.path}\") ?: T(java.nio.file.Files).createTempDirectory(\"test\")}")
private final Path path;
```

This works when `base.path` is specified in `application.properties` but if it is not it results in:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'base.path' in value "#{T(java.nio.file.Paths).get("${base.path}") ?: T(java.nio.file.Files).createTempDirectory("test")}"

So I tried to use a conditional operator:

```java
@Value("#{ base.path != null ? T(java.nio.file.Paths).get(\"${base.path}\") : T(java.nio.file.Files).createTempDirectory(\"test\")}")
// as well as:
@Value("#{ ${base.path} != null ? T(java.nio.file.Paths).get(\"${base.path}\") : T(java.nio.file.Files).createTempDirectory(\"test\")}")
```

but it still results in

> Could not resolve placeholder 'base.path' in value "#{ base.path != null ? T(java.nio.file.Paths).get("${base.path}") : T(java.nio.file.Files).createTempDirectory("test")}"

I could achieve this with a configuration file but I'd like to avoid doing this:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BasePathConfig {
    @Value("${base.path:#{null}}")
    private final String basePath;

    @Bean
    public Path basePath() throws IOException {
        if (basePath == null) {
            return Files.createTempDirectory(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        }
        return Paths.get(basePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Value("#{'${base.path:xxxx}' != 'xxxx' " +
        "? T(java.nio.file.Paths).get('${base.path:}') " +
        ": T(java.nio.file.Files).createTempDirectory('test')}")
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to compare with `null` instead of specifying a string? I tried it with `#{null}` but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Not that I am aware of; just pick a String value that would be impossible in a path, such as `"#{'${base.path:#}' != '#' "`.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the base.path a default value of null with the `${property.name:default}` mechanism:

```
@Value("#{ ${base.path:null} != null ? T(java.nio.file.Paths).get(\"${base.path}\") : T(java.nio.file.Files).createTempDirectory(\"test\")}")
```

Comment: This would be my preferred way to do this by comparing to 'null' but unfortunately your example didn't work as I believe it would compare to the literal string 'null'. I tried it with `#{null}` instead but it still didn't work.